# Python Adwords API suds.sudsobject Parse Response Containing Empty Indexed Key?

Tags: python, soap, suds, google-ads-api

I have a suds object:

```
<class 'suds.sudsobject.AdGroupPage'>
```

Suds response:

```
(AdGroupPage){
   totalNumEntries = 1
   Page.Type = "AdGroupPage"
   entries[] = 
      (AdGroup){
         id = 38496562285
         campaignId = 759990659
         campaignName = "Some Campaign #1"
         name = "Second group"
         status = "ENABLED"
         biddingStrategyConfiguration = 
            (BiddingStrategyConfiguration){
               biddingStrategyType = "MANUAL_CPC"
               bids[] = 
                  (CpcBid){
                     Bids.Type = "CpcBid"
                     bid = 
                        (Money){
                           ComparableValue.Type = "Money"
                           microAmount = 1230000
                        }
                     cpcBidSource = "ADGROUP"
                  },
            }
      },
 }
```

I'm trying to create a `SET` operation with Google Adwords API to change an adgroup bid to something else using an Adwords API mutate operation.

This is my attempt in **PYTHON**:

```
operations = [{
    'operator': 'SET',
    'operand': {
        'id': 38496562285,
        'biddingStrategyConfiguration': {
            'bids': [{
                'bid': {
                    'microAmount': 4560000
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }]
```

The error from my request is:

```
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'bid'
```

Here's a simple example that successfully works:

```
operations = [{
      'operator': 'SET',
      'operand': {
          'id': ad_group_id,
          'status': 'PAUSED'
      }
  }]
```

**My problem is, I don't know how to handle the `bids[]` syntax** from the suds response. How should I modify my dictionary to work with an empty list key?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had to include something called `xsi_type`. In-case anyone stumbles across this question, this is what my `operations` object looked like:

```
operations = [{
      'operator': 'SET',
      'operand': {
        'id': 38496562285,
        'biddingStrategyConfiguration': {
          'bids': [{
            'xsi_type': 'CpcBid',
            'bid': {'microAmount': 4560000}
            }]
          }
        }
      }]
```

Here is a link to [v201609 AdGroupService.BiddingStrategyConfiguration](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201609/AdGroupService.BiddingStrategyConfiguration). It doesn't mention `xsi_type` but if you encounter a field like `bids[]`, you now know to try to define `xsi_type` in your operation.